# What's the difference between Jumpbox and Microsoft App-V?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines

My organisation has been using [App-V](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/mdop/app-v.aspx) to package deployments to users machines in a Windows environment.

We're now evaluating [Jumpbox](http://www.jumpbox.com/) as a replacement in this space.

The great thing about App-V was that the application could run on the remote server, but the user had the experience of running an application locally.

From what I can see, Jumpbox is a virtual-machine client (ie the virtual machine is running locally, and you have a second machine to log-in to, a similar user experience to using terminal server).

Perhaps I don't have this correct. My question is: **What's the difference between Jumpbox and Microsoft App-V?**

Answer (score 1):

The most important difference I can see between the two services is that App-V enables you to virtualize almost any application in-house and deliver it to your users, whereas Jump Box is a collection of 50 pre-chosen applications you can use in your environment. These applications are varied and when I flipped through I saw PostgreSQL, some blogging platforms, and a few other things.

So, really what matters is if the prepackaged applications Jump box covers the needs of your users. If you need to applications not offered by Jump Box, then it's not your tool.